# JQuery: All Submenu's expand if a child in one has class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, submenu

I have a little piece of code that expands a submenu by adding the class "in" to the parent if a child element contains the class "current_page_item". The problem is, if any submenus have a child of that class they all expand.

```
if ( $('.children li').hasClass('current_page_item') ) {
     $('.children', this)
        .addClass('in');
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n94Lwe9t/

I can't target ID's or anything else specific. How would I target the particular parent that has that child class?

Comment: try with $('.children>li')

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it :(  https://jsfiddle.net/n94Lwe9t/2/

Comment: try this $('li.current_page_item').parents('ul')
   .addClass('in')

Comment: That works but doesn't address the glyphicon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the child elements li of `children` class and then use `closest()` to find the appropriate parent

```
$('.children li').each(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('current_page_item')) {
    console.log($(this).closest('.has-children').find('.list-group-item .glyphicon'));
    $(this).closest('.has-children').find('.list-group-item .glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down')
     $(this).closest('.children').addClass('in');
  }

})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n94Lwe9t/3/)**

Comment: This worked thank you! I'm not the greatest with loops yet.